# Face problem on render

Tags: mesh, edges, faces

Screenshots will explain my problem. Im talking about strange shadows.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your file? Watching the image could be Doubles . . . Select all the mesh- press w - Remove Doubles

Comment: It isn't doubles

Comment: I know why it is looking like this. I used 'disolve edges'. No way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is simply a question of lamps . . . You added too many (5-6 lamps all around the mesh with a sun too) then the shadows overlap. Delete all the light point you created and let only one in front of the mesh.

Check the image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad to help ;)